# Lravel 5.4: JWT API with multi-auth on two tables one works the other not

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, laravel-5.4

I am using...

- Laravel 5.4
- tymon/jwt-auth : 1.0.0-rc.2

I have application with two authentications API one is `customers` and the other is `drivers` each one has it's own table.

now let me describe shortly `JWT` package installation and the updates I did on it.

- I installed the package as described in the [JWT](http://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/) documents exactly.
- Now comes to the [quick start](http://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/) here I updated two `Models` one is the `User` and the second `Driver`.
- Comes here to the `Configure Auth guard` again I used the configuration for the two `guards` let me show a snapshot of my `auth.php`.

  ```
  'defaults' => [
      'guard'     => 'api',
      'passwords' => 'users',
  ], 

  'guards' => [
          'web' => [
              'driver'   => 'session',
              'provider' => 'users',
          ],

          'api' => [
              'driver'   => 'jwt',
              'provider' => 'users',
          ],

          'driver'    => [
              'driver'   => 'session',
              'provider' => 'drivers',
          ],

          'driver-api' => [
              'driver'   => 'jwt',
              'provider' => 'drivers',
          ],
      ],

  'providers' => [
          'users'     => [
              'driver' => 'eloquent',
              'model'  => App\Models\User::class,
          ],

          'drivers'   => [
              'driver' => 'eloquent',
              'model'  => App\Models\Driver::class,
          ],
      ],
  ```
- Now continue the application with `authentication routes` here is my `Routes` for the two `Models`

Here is the `User` and `Driver` Routes

```
Route::group( [
    'prefix'     => 'auth',
    'middleware' => 'api'
], function () {
    .......
});

Route::group( [
    'prefix'     => 'driver',
    'middleware' => 'api'
], function () {
   .......
});
```

- Now comes the `AuthController`

in the `JWT` documentation the `construct` is writing like that.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }
```

I found some article that suggest to make it something like this to switch between the two models we have.

so here with my controller looks like now.

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->user   = new User;
        $this->driver = new Driver;
    }

public function userLogin( Request $request ) {
        Config::set( 'jwt.user', 'App\Models\User' );
        Config::set( 'auth.providers.users.model', User::class );
        $credentials = $request->only( 'email', 'password' );
        $token       = null;
        try {
            if ( $token = $this->guard()->attempt( $credentials ) ) {
                return response()->json( [
                    'response' => 'error',
                    'message'  => 'invalid_email_or_password',
                ] );
            }
        } catch ( JWTAuthException $e ) {
            return response()->json( [
                'response' => 'error',
                'message'  => 'failed_to_create_token',
            ] );
        }

        return response()->json( [
            'response' => 'success',
            'result'   => [
                'token'   => $token,
                'message' => 'I am front user',
            ],
        ] );
    }

    public function driverLogin( Request $request ) {
        Config::set( 'jwt.user', 'App\Models\Driver' );
        Config::set( 'auth.providers.users.model', Driver::class );
        $credentials = $request->only( 'email', 'password' );
        $token       = null;
        try {
            if ( ! $token = $this->guard()->attempt( $credentials ) ) {
                return response()->json( [
                    'response' => 'error',
                    'message'  => 'invalid_email_or_password',
                ] );
            }
        } catch ( JWTAuthException $e ) {
            return response()->json( [
                'response' => 'error',
                'message'  => 'failed_to_create_token',
            ] );
        }

        return response()->json( [
            'response' => 'success',
            'result'   => [
                'token'   => $token,
                'message' => 'I am driver user',
            ],
        ] );
    }

public function me() {
        return response()->json( $this->guard()->user() );
    }

public function logout() {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        return response()->json( [ 'message' => 'Successfully logged out' ] );
    }

public function refresh() {
        return $this->respondWithToken( $this->guard()->refresh() );
    }

protected function respondWithToken( $token ) {
        return response()->json( [
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type'   => 'bearer',
            'expires_in'   => $this->guard()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ] );
    }

public function guard() {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
```

> Now with is happening and the problems I faced

Now the driver `api` is working as `login` only Ex.

`localhost:8000/api/driver/login` Working fine

but when try to get the driver user `id` like this

`localhost:8000/api/driver/me` it return empty `array`

> Second Issue comes.

the use login from the `interface` for Ex. `http://localhost:8000/login` it returns back to the login screen without any errors becouse the login information is right but the `defaults` in the `auth.php` is `'guard'=>'api'` if I change it to `'guard'=>'web'` it do the login correctly.

even the `User API` for Ex. `localhost:8000/api/auth/login` always return

```
{
    "response": "error",
    "message": "invalid_email_or_password"
}
```

**Update**

> I solved half the way
>   I updated the `AuthController` to be something like this.

```
public function __construct() {
        if ( Request()->url() == '/api/driver/me' ) {
            $this->middleware( 'auth:driver-api', [ 'except' => [ 'login' ] ] );
        } elseif ( Request()->url() == '/api/customer/me' ) {
            $this->middleware( 'auth:api', [ 'except' => [ 'login' ] ] );
        }
    }
```

and the login function to be something like this.

```
public function login() {
        if ( Request()->url() == '/api/driver' ) {
            Config::set( 'auth.providers.users.model', Driver::class );
            $credentials = request( [ 'email', 'password' ] );

            if ( ! $token = auth()->attempt( $credentials ) ) {
                return response()->json( [ 'error' => 'Unauthorized' ], 401 );
            }

            return $this->respondWithToken( $token );
        }

        Config::set( 'auth.providers.users.model', User::class );
        $credentials = request( [ 'email', 'password' ] );

        if ( ! $token = auth()->attempt( $credentials ) ) {
            return response()->json( [ 'error' => 'Unauthorized' ], 401 );
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken( $token );

    }
```

but still have problem in `auth.php` here it is

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard'     => 'driver-api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

here I need to switch the `'guard'=>'api'` to be `'guard'=>'driver-api'` in case if URL request is `localhost:8000/api/driver/login` and `'guard'=>'api'` in case if URL request is `localhost:8000/api/customer/login` any way to do this.

**Update 2**

Here is the `driver` `Model`

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Driver extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject {
    protected $guard = 'driver';

    protected $fillable = [
        ...
        'email',
        'password',
        ...
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims() {
        return [];
    }
}
```

and the `User` `Model`

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject {
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier() {
            return $this->getKey();
        }

        public function getJWTCustomClaims() {
            return [];
        }
```

I need some help, Ideas please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me thank you @AmrAbdelRahman for you efforts and your time.

My problem was the application always using my `default authentication "guard"` as my default looks like that

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard'     => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

so every time I try to authenticate the other user which was the driver it fails during the default authenticate is `api` and the it should using `driver` in this case.

what I did in my case was making a switcher in my `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` under the `boot` here is how it looks like

```
$this->app['router']->matched(function (\Illuminate\Routing\Events\RouteMatched $e) {
            $route = $e->route;
            if (!array_has($route->getAction(), 'guard')) {
                return;
            }
            $routeGuard = array_get($route->getAction(), 'guard');
            $this->app['auth']->resolveUsersUsing(function ($guard = null) use ($routeGuard) {
                return $this->app['auth']->guard($routeGuard)->user();
            });
            $this->app['auth']->setDefaultDriver($routeGuard);
        });
```

Now in my case if the `$guard =api` it will read that `guard` and act correctly and if it's `driver` it will use the new `guard` and act as expected. Hope this will help some one in future.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to change the providers in `config/auth.php`.

You can change the `__construct` function in each of your controllers as follows. So that jwt know which model to authenticate.

**DriverController**

```
function __construct()
{
    Config::set('jwt.user', Driver::class);
    Config::set('auth.providers', ['users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Driver::class,
        ]]);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain it?

Answer (score 3):

My example when i used multi auth with jwt

I have 2 models :
1. users
2. admins

the routes :

```
Route::post('auth/userlogin', 'ApiController@userLogin');
Route::post('auth/adminlogin', 'ApiController@adminLogin');
```

the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Config;
use JWTAuth;
use JWTAuthException;
use App\User;
use App\Admin;

class ApiController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new User;
        $this->admin = new Admin;
    }

    public function userLogin(Request $request){
        Config::set('jwt.user', 'App\User'); 
        Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\User::class);
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $token = null;
        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'response' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'invalid_email_or_password',
                ]);
            }
        } catch (JWTAuthException $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'response' => 'error',
                'message' => 'failed_to_create_token',
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'response' => 'success',
            'result' => [
                'token' => $token,
                'message' => 'I am front user',
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function adminLogin(Request $request){
        Config::set('jwt.user', 'App\Admin'); 
        Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Admin::class);
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $token = null;
        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'response' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'invalid_email_or_password',
                ]);
            }
        } catch (JWTAuthException $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'response' => 'error',
                'message' => 'failed_to_create_token',
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'response' => 'success',
            'result' => [
                'token' => $token,
                'message' => 'I am Admin user',
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

I hope that's help you .

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/164356) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable.

Comment: @AmrAbdelRahman Thanks really for taking time to replay. I did the same ting like you did but what about the `@me` controller as shown in the documentation `return response()->json( $user = auth()->user() );` I can now get the first user information but the second user comes `{}` empty array can you please clear this for me

Comment: sure, you would get only with the current user try to login
($user = auth()->user() ) !!
Are you want to get all users?

Comment: No just the login user steps as I try on `postman` I try this first `api/auth/userlogin` fine got the `token` and then trying this `api/auth/user/me` got the user information then the next step try the admin for example `api/auth/adminlogin` got the `token` then try `api/auth/admin/me` got `{}` empty array that whats happening exactly

Comment: now, i understood what happened with you.
hmm,please check drivers,controller,routes,models!

Comment: @AmrAbdelRahman see my original question I have added my `drivers` and `Routes` and will update my question now and add the `Models` for you to see

Comment: @AmrAbdelRahman I updated my question please review the Models

Comment: where are the admin model?!